# jQuery Theme does not change for one element – CSS Framework

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a button and a div in my html page. Initially I used Redmond theme and then I changed to Ui-lightness theme. The div element properly shows the Ui-lightness theme. But the button is still showing the Redmond theme.  How do we correct it?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<%--redmond--%>
<%--<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.13/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />--%>

<%--ui-lightness--%>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

<div>
    <button id="cancel" type="button"
            class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
            Cancel
    </button>
</div>

<div id="mybox" 
     class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" 
     style="margin-top: 20px;
     width: 300px; 
     height: 150px;">

    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Widget Heading Text</h3>
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-comment" style="margin: 0 2px 0 2px; float: left;"></span>
        This is a test sentence.
    </p>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Great, just getting that out of the way. Beyond that, i can just recommend actually downloading the theme and all associated images, instead of referencing the google code one. As for your other question, there's a gallery of all the official jQuery ui themes at http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ and you can also make and download your own custom theme there, if you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned you did clear browser cache, the probable reason would be the style you have applied to button is incorrect, it should be `ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only`.

The button should look like

```
<button id="button" 
  class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"
  role="button" aria-disabled="false">
  <span class="ui-button-text">A button element</span>
</button>
```

according to the jQuery Site.

And check, modify and download themes from [jQuery Website.](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Redmond : http://jsfiddle.net/kskHX/   ui-lightness : http://jsfiddle.net/kskHX/1/

Answer (score 0):

The reason why button not changing style is probobly browser cache (CTRL + R in most browsers) or something else on your page overwrites style.

Examples can be found here:

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/